# How does a Java Application know if a new JIRA ticket is created?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to come up with a Java application that has to monitor a JIRA project for new ticket and if ticket is created then get details about the issue described in the ticket.

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve the same. From other stackoverflow question I saw about webhooks and from the jira docs I came to know about [Listeners](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/listeners-867028226.html) which I believe is more like event registering and listening however I am not sure what is the best approach.

Comment: If you had idea about eclipse plugin the checkout Mylyn Project https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/

Comment: @Shashwat Please can you elaborate a bit more on your comment

Comment: Two options: Either poll the Jira service for a ticket, or get the Jira service to ping you (e.g. with a webhook) when a ticket is created. Which you choose depends on your use case.